# How to get a cookie value in Woocommerce email notifications?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce, email-notifications

I'm retrieving a value using php cookies from a plugin to woocommerce thankyou page and customer order detail page, it works fine on thankyou page but didn't print anything on email order detail page, how would I fix this?

I have tried fetching values using php sessions, it prints value only for 10 to 15 minutes, after that it doesn't print anything, can anyone help me to retrieve values using PHP cookie.

From here I want to fetch Post ID

```
  <?php
  if('on' == $display_ticket_number){
        echo '#' . $post->ID . ' ';
  }

  echo $post->post_title; 

 $ticketid = $post->ID; 
 setcookie ("ticketidno",$ticketid, time() +60, "/");  
 ?>
```

On thankyou.php it prints value

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE["ticketidno"];?>
```

email-order-details.php here it doesn't print

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE["ticketidno"];?>
```

---

**Edit**

I want to get and display cookie value on:

1. Email Notification, for `emails/email-order-details.php` template file on this hook:

   ```
   do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>
   ```

   So before Order Table.
2. Text SMS Plugin: `plugins/woocommerce-apg-sms-notifications/includes/admin/proveedores.php`

   ```
   case "solutions_infini":
       $respuesta = wp_remote_get( "http://api-global.solutionsinfini.com/v3/?api_key=" . $apg_sms_settings['clave_solutions_infini'] . "&method=sms" . "&to=" . $telefono . "&sender=" . $apg_sms_settings['identificador_solutions_infini'] . "&message=" . "Thanks for Registering in ". $_SESSION['post_title'] . " your Registration ID no is THR". $_COOKIE["ticketidno"] . apg_sms_codifica_el_mensaje( $mensaje ));
       break;
   ```

Replacing `$_COOKIE["ticketidno"]`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I were you I would use the session variable because cookies can be disabled from the user. In this case you whole function won't work. Maybe there is also something which deletes the cookies. So try it with $_SESSION['']

Comment: I have tried fetching values using php sessions, it prints value only for 10 to 15 minutes, after that it doesn't print anything.

Comment: So there is a function or something else which ends / clears your session, cookies and everything. Seems wired. Can be everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

You should need to grab the cookie value as custom order meta data in thankyou "Order received" page:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_grab_cookie_as_meta_data', 10, 1 );
function thankyou_grab_cookie_as_meta_data( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ){
        return;
    }

    if( isset($_COOKIE["ticketidno"]) && ! get_post_meta( $order_id, '_cookie_ticketidno', true ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cookie_ticketidno', esc_attr($_COOKIE["ticketidno"]) );
    }
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

The you will be able to get this grabbed cookie value using:

1. From the Order ID: `$cookie = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_cookie_ticketidno', true );`
2. From the Order Object: `$order->get_meta( '_cookie_ticketidno' ); // (on Woocommerce 3+)`

---

Display in email notifications:

```
// Email notifications display
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_order_instruction_email', 5, 4 );
function add_order_instruction_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( $value = $order->get_meta('_cookie_ticketidno') )
        echo '<p class="ticket-id">' .__('Ticket Id Number: ') . $value . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

Display on "Order received" page (thankyou):

```
// On "Order received" page (on start)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'thankyou_custom_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
function thankyou_custom_order_received_text( $text, $order ) {
    if ( $value = $order->get_meta('_cookie_ticketidno') ) {
        $text .= '<br><div class="ticket-id"><p>' . __('Ticket Id Number: ') . $value . '</p></div>' ;
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

For SMS - As this requires the order ID, try the following without any guaranty:

```
    case "solutions_infini":

        $respuesta = wp_remote_get( "http://api-global.solutionsinfini.com/v3/?api_key=" . $apg_sms_settings['clave_solutions_infini'] . "&method=sms" . "&to=" . $telefono . "&sender=" . $apg_sms_settings['identificador_solutions_infini'] . "&message=" . "Thanks for Registering in ". $_SESSION['post_title'] . " your Registration ID no is THR". get_post_meta( $_SESSION['ID'], '_cookie_ticketidno', true ) . apg_sms_codifica_el_mensaje( $mensaje ));
        break;
```

Code should goes on proveedores.php file in your plugin, Just replacing in the code:

```
$_COOKIE["ticketidno"]
```

by:

```
get_post_meta( $_SESSION['ID'], '_cookie_ticketidno', true )
```

where `$_SESSION['ID']` *(I suppose and I hope)* should be **the order ID**.

Comment: I tried both, but it doesn't print anything even on thankyou.php page.

Comment: As I can see, value are saved in wp_postmeta database table under _cookie_ticketidno meta_key but i am not able to print them on any page with given codes.
Can you help me to print ?

Comment: First Code Works for me, second code doesn't save value in database.
I want to print on two pages:
1. wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php
2). wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-apg-sms-notifications/includes/admin/proveedores.php

2nd one is for SMS Text.